# Binding a list of rectangles to a canvas in AvaloniaUI

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to bind an observable collection of rectangles to an items control with a canvas as the item panel, but there seems to be no way of binding the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties to the Rectangle items. I attempted to do this by adding a ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle like one would in WPF, but this doesn't seem to exist in Avalonia.
I searched and found this: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/10018
However, I couldn't find any reference to ItemContainerTheme on the Avalonia documentation.

This is what I have currently:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Items="{Binding Rectangles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is the view model for each item that the items template is binding to:

```
public class RectangleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _x = 0;
    public int X
    {
        get => _x;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _x, value);
    }

    private int _y = 0;
    public int Y
    {
        get => _y;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _y, value);
    }

    private int _width = 0;
    public int Width
    {
        get => _width;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _width, value);
    }

    private int _height = 0;
    public int Height
    {
        get => _height;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _height, value);
    }
}
```

And this is my Rectangles collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel> Rectangles { get; } = new();
```

Comment: I *think* (and that's why this is a comment, not an answer,) that `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` are attached properties, and as such they work differently. I have never tried to change an attached property via a style setter. Perhaps it does not work? Or perhaps it does not work in Avalonia?

Comment: have you try ItemsControl.ItemContainerTheme instead of ItemContainerStyle?  https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/10060

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't find any reference to ItemContainerTheme on the documentation. It must be more complicated than replacing ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle with ItemsControl.ItemContainerTheme, since it's throwing not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I managed to find a somewhat related Github issue here https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/2302 that uses the attached `Styles` attribute to add the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties.
The fixed result:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Items="{Binding Rectangles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.Styles>
        <Style Selector="ItemsControl > ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Styles>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Stroke="#00FF00" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Transparent" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This does not appear to work with compiled bindings, how can that be fixed?

Comment: @nietras It should work just fine with compiled bindings as long as you specify DataType for the DataTemplate and x:DataType for the Style.